# Загрузка Live Linux Ubuntu с USB не получается

Tags: linux, usb

Ноутбук Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Nano Gen1. Пытаюсь загрузить с флэшки Linux после нажатия F11. Вижу в списке флэшку, тыкаю на неё, экран в биосе мигает и ничего. Эта же флэшка работает на загрузку с неё на другом ноуте(проверял). Может настройки какие в биос, кто знает?

Comment: Да, скорее всего, какие-то настройки в биос.

Comment: Вот вопрос и в этом) Может знает кто биос от Леново?)

Comment: Да нет такого "биос от Леново", ну чо как... У них на каждой линейке своё, и каждые пять лет - новое.

Comment: @atmos-fear, биос от Леново изучают на втором курсе в шаолиньских монастырях. А если серьезно то проблема либо в BOIS/UEFI то есть попробуйте переключиться на старый биос в настройках; либо проблема из за включенного Secure Boot(ну или как то так) в биосе, попробуйте отключить его.

Comment: Получилось! Мне это и нужно было услышать) Всё загрузилось. Правда, Windows перестала загружаться, просит какой-то ключ, если в BIOS Secure Boot отключен. Включил его опять, всё заработало. Вы мне очень помогли! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Старые биосы с EFI не видят файловой системы ISO9660.

Такой компьютер может все-таки  загрузиться с MBR при отключении EFI : в BIOS Setup выставить Legacy boot.

Но можно запуститься и с EFI: флешку переформатируйте в FAT32 и запишите диск копированием файлов на этот раздел через программу Unetbootin (или подобную).